# Can we relate $C_0$ and $C_b$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and denote by $C_0(X)$ all continuous functions vanishing at infinity and by $C_b(X)$ all the bounded continuous functions. It's easy to see that $C_0(X)\subseteq C_b(X)$. For $C_0(X)$ it is possible to use the Lemma of Machado to approximate it's elements by elements of a suitable subalgebra. I would like to have a similar approximation of elements of $C_b(X)$.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to characterise $C_b(X)$ in terms of $C_0(X)$ in order to apply Machado's Lemma?
2. Is it possible to prove Machados Lemma on $C_b(X)$?

**My guess**

1: No, without knowing what exactly $X$ is, it's impossible to characterise $C_b(X)$ via $C_0(X)$. But even in the simplest case $X=\mathbb{R}$ there is no hope. An oscillating function like $\sin\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ does not even converge at $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

2: So the book of Searcoid does not mention the $C_b(X)$-case at all, but for me it seems that the proof of Machado's Lemma should also work. But I have the feeling I miss something.

Comment: Are you asking for a topology on $C_b(X)$ such that $C_0(X)$ is dense in $C_b(X)$?

Comment: You could provide links to this Machado's Lemma... or, the statement...

Comment: @AndréCaldas sadly only on the german wikipedia one finds Machado's lemma under Bishops theorem. Here: https://second.wiki/wiki/satz_von_bishop you can find the statement.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I don't really want to touch the topology on $C_b$ since i would like to keep the supremum-norm. I didn't specify it in the question, but for my application it's important to have the supremum-norm.

Comment: Why not just look at the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$ of $X$ instead?

Comment: @user10354138 Because $C_b(X) \cong C(\beta X)$, so the OP is already considering the Stone-Cech compactification.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I mean if OP want an approximation result there is an obvious way to get that from $C(\beta X)$.

Comment: You say that it is impossible to characterise $C_b(X)$ using $C_0(X)$. This is false: the multiplier algebra $M(C_0(X)) \cong C_b(X) \cong C(\beta X)$

Answer (score 1):

$C_0(X)$ is closed in $C_b(X)$, so there is no hope to approximate elements in $C_b(X)$ by elements in $C_0(X)$. However, there is something else you can do.

Consider on $C_b(X)$ the so-called strict topology (in fact, this is simply the topology we obtain by looking at $M(C_0(X)) = C_b(X)$), which is the locally convex topological space generated by the seminorms
$$C_b(X)\ni f \mapsto \|gf\|, \quad g \in C_0(X).$$

One can show that $C_0(X)$ is strictly dense in $C_b(X)$ (via an approximate unit argument), and thus for every element $f \in C_b(X)$, there is a net $\{g_\lambda\}\subseteq C_0(X)$ such that
$$\lim_\lambda \|g_\lambda g - fg\| = 0$$
for all $g \in C_0(X)$.

Comment: And do you perhaps have an idea how to use this for a proof of Machado's lemma in $C_b(X)$?

Comment: @Proxava I'm not sure what result you want to prove. Can you clarify?